# no saved Failed looking up window in flutter

Tags: android, flutter

when install app in nox-player(android 5.1),app installed but when click on,
app crashed , and get this problem :
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I was on stable channel, when switch to master channel and updated flutter, this problem occurred,and again switch to stable channel and my problem sloved
I do not know why this problem occurred!